# Get CA certificate that is used to check server certificate

Tags: c#, ssl, x509

I have a simple console app in (.NET / C#) that is creating a TLS connection. The connection is working and I can send a `ping` to the server that will reply with a `pong`. The code to send and receive is omitted, minimal example is this.

```
internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string server = "172.16.62.21";
        TcpClient client = new TcpClient(server, 8081);

        using (SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(client.GetStream(), false,
            new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate), null))
        {
            sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(server);

            // Sending ping here 
            // Reading pong reply here

            Console.WriteLine("waiting for keypress");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        client.Close();
    }

    public static bool ValidateServerCertificate(object sender, X509Certificate? certificate,
    X509Chain? chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

As I have a TLS connection (verified with Wireshark), and because this example works, I assume that I have a secured connection.

Is there any way that I can check which CA certificate is used on the client side (this program) to validate the server certificate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> As I have a TLS connection (verified with Wireshark), and because this example works, I assume that I have a secured connection.

Well, it's secure only in that it's encrypted. But the encryption relies on you accepting *any* certificate, even self-signed or untrusted CA, so anyone can MITM.

> Is there any way that I can check wich CA certificate is used on the client side (this program) to validate the server certificate ?

There isn't a root certificate because you haven't validated anything. You've just gone `return true` so accepting it regardless.

Either way, you can output the last element of the `X509Chain`, and this will be the root CA certificate, or the highest up the chain that could be found.

```cs
public static bool ValidateServerCertificate(object sender, X509Certificate? certificate,
    X509Chain? chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
    var lastChainElement = chain.ChainElements.Last();

    Console.WriteLine(lastChainElement.Certificate.ToString());

    return sslPolicyErrors == 0;
}
```

Comment: A) the chain already comes pre-built, you don't need to call Build again.  B) Rather than checking at the individual cert level like you do, the right answer would be to just use the return from Build ("did this match the stated policy?")  C) Since Build was already called, if it returned false then sslPolicyErrors will have the chain-errors bit set.  So you can delete the call to chain.Build and the return is just `return sslPolicyErrors == 0;`

Comment: OK didn't realize that thanks. In the original edit I wasn't checking individual certs, OP just wanted to see what the CA cert was so I output that. The actual verification was based on the Build result.

Comment: @bartonjs Indeed I want to know which CA cert is used to validate the server cert. As there are tons of CA certs in a windows machine, I want to find out which of them is used to do the verification.

Comment: After some playing around with the certificates that I have, I manage to get the `sslPolicyErrors` to be 0. Removing the trusted root certificate then will cause `sslPolicyErrors` to be non-zero.